# Next year. Vs in next year

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

> I'll see you **in** the next class.

This sentence sounds more correct than

> I'll see you next class.

But why in the following_

> We'll meet next year.

Vs

> We'll meet **in** next year.

Here the first one (sentence without "in") sounds more natural? Is the second one grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your class example is ambiguous.  Do you mean

> I'll see you in the next geography class *(possibly next week)*.
>   ***I'll see you in the next class.***

or

> I'll see you in the class right after this one.
>   ***I'll see you next class.*** *(possible)*
>   ***I'll see you in the following class.*** *(best)*

In your examples

> **We'll meet next year.** *(good)*
>   **We'll meet in next year.** *(incorrect)*
>   **We'll meet in the next year** *(has a different meaning)*
>   **We'll meet in the new year.** *(best)*

Comment: What's the difference between -  I'll see you next Year. Vs I'll see you in the next year ? Could you please tell ?

Comment: Depending on context, "I'll see you next year." usually would mean the early part of the year and is more habitual, whereas "in the next year" can mean any time within 365 days and would probably mean later in the year or possibly even the following year than just "next year".